# Depth first search in java - how to go back to parent node?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm trying to do a depth first search in Java recursively. At the moment, the code runs through my graph fine, but it never backtracks to find a route when they're are no more nodes to visit. I'm having a bit of a mental block honestly. What would be the best way to go back to the parent node?

Here is my code so far:

```
private final Map<Character, Node> mNodes;
private final List<Edge> mEdges;

public DepthFirstSearch(Graph graph){
    mNodes = graph.getNodes();
    mEdges = new ArrayList<>(graph.getEdges());
    for(Node node : mNodes.values()){
        node.setVisited(false);
    }
}

public void depthFirstSearch(Node source){
    source.setVisited(true);
    List<Node> neighbours = source.getNeighbours(mEdges);
    for(Node node : neighbours){
            if(!node.isVisited()){
                System.out.println(node.getName());
                depthFirstSearch(node);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the getNeighbour code:

```
public List<Node> getNeighbours(List<Edge> edges) {
        List<Node> neighbours = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Edge edge : edges){
            if(edge.getFrom().equals(this)){
                neighbours.add(edge.getTo());
            }
        }
        return neighbours;
    }
```

Added code for trying Jager's idea:

```
public void depthFirstSearch(Node source){
        source.setVisited(true);
        List<Edge> neighbours = source.getNeighbouringEdges(mEdges);
        for(Edge edge : neighbours){
                if(!edge.getTo().isVisited()){
                    System.out.println(edge.getTo().getName());
                    depthFirstSearch(edge.getTo());
                }else{
                    depthFirstSearch(edge.getFrom());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Every time a recursive invocation returns, that basically "goes up" to the parent that invoked it. Recursion is definitely a case where it's very helpful to sit down with a pencil and paper and write down each step of what's going on.

Comment: Post the code for source.getNeighbours(mEdges); That'll help us see if you're getting all the neighbors in the first place.

Comment: included all the code

Comment: Sorry for this unuseful comment, but I'm struggling to properly understand you data structure. I see you have a separated list for the edges, and a map of nodes, it doesn't seem very practical (the getNeighbours procedure has to iterate through the whole list for instance). What about using a Map<Character, Node>, and inside each node another Map<Node, Edge> to describe neighbours? Nothing important anyway, but it might help with debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Well, typically you have a root node that has children. Each child can have children of its own. So you would rather do:

```
public void depthFirstSearch(Node source)
{
    for(Node node : source.getChildren())
    {
        System.out.println(node.getName());
        depthFirstSearch(node);
        // and right here you get your back tracking implicitly:
        System.out.println("back at " + node.getName());
    }
}
```

Note that I do not have a necessity for a member `visited`...

**Edit:**

Now that you provided your data structure, let me propose another approach:

```
class Node
{
    // all that you have so far...

    private char mId;
    private List<Node> mChildren = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public char getId()
    {
        return mId;
    }
    public List<Node> getChildren()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
    }

    // appropriate methods to add new children
}
```

The id replaces the key of your map. Then you simply have a root `Node mRoot` to start with somewhere. This is the typical way to implement trees.

You might want to go up from a child node directly. Then you'd additionally need a `private Node parent;` in the node class (immediately being set to `this` when adding a child to the private list and set to null, when being removed). You won't use this for backtracking, though, so the depth first search above remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing: you are "getting" the neighbors for **mEdges** which seems to be a field of the surrounding class.

Most likely, you should ask each node for **its own** edges upon visiting it.

Comment: I think you're onto something. Will give it a bash.

Comment: The code I've tried gives me a stack overflow, added it to the main question